# How to know the correct path to extend in Magento?

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, folder

I am new in Magento. I am having a lot of problems to achieve each step in the learning curve.
I needed to add a custom shipping method. I was fallowging this tutorial:
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/
Is not working for me, maybe because multiple causes. But for example, I see the class Shipping is extending from "\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier" but I don´t have this path in my Magento folder. 
I have Magento CE 2.1. 
That changes for each version? I am really confused, :(. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you looking for path for Magento core modules, you could check on this folder :

`<magento_root>/vendor/magento/*`

especially for the module that you mention `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier` you could get that class file on this path`<magento_root>/vendor/magento/module-shipping/model/carrier/AbstractCarrier.php`

Comment: Great @mrfizh sounds good. Thanks for your answer. I realized now that this notation(a/b/c/d) is for namespacing nesting and not related with the file path.

Comment: you're welcome glad to help you. yes that right, magento 2 uses that notation as namespacing, you will get same case with 3rd plugin that installed from the composer

Comment: Hey @mrfizh sorry for bother you. I am receiving this error now, after follow steps of the tutorial. Any Ideas? (or do you have better tutorial to read to add custom shipping methos? I really need to add them dinamically).
"Fatal error: Class Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Countable::se) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Config\FileIterator.php"

Comment: hmm, I think it's better for you to create new question again, and post your code that already you wrote, it will make easy for me and other users to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

When you extend any file ( which is in vendor/magento/module-x folder ) its path is always start with **\Magento\X** so in your case if you are extending file from **module-shipping** then its path would be **\Magento\Shipping\**.

so here you will see **module** is replaced with **Magento** and module name will be named with first letter capital i.e **shipping** will become **Shipping**.